# Is it possible to have the read/write of a property to have different visibility?

Tags: delphi, language-features

As the question says... is it possible to declare the read/write of a property at different level of visibility. If so, what would be the syntax?

Something along the line of :

```
  protected
    property MyProp : Integer write FMyProp;
  public
    property MyProp : Integer read FMyProp;
  end;
```

Not that it would be a major language feature, it's easily replaced by

```
protected
  procedure SetMyProp(Value : Integer);
public
  property MyProp : Integer read FMyProp;
end;
```

I'm just curious if such a possibility exists.

Comment: If you want that, then just use a private or protected Set method (SetPropName) instead of putting it in the public or published property.  You have to use object.SetPropName(x) instead of object.PropName := x, which is fine.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you use _interfaces_ such a construct comes naturally. In the interface, the property would be read-only. In the class, it would be read/write and protected.

Answer (score 9):

No, you have to split it into two separate properties (with different names), although they can refer to the same private field.

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible. I'm not sure why you would need to do that, however.

The only reason I can see is to make it read-only while still allowing it to be published and seen in the Object Inspector, and you can already do this:

```
private
  procedure SetMyProp(Value: String);
published
  MyProp: string read FMyProp write SetMyProp;

...
procedure TMyComponent.SetMyProp(Value: String);
begin
  //
end;
```

Comment: C# has asymmetric property accessors since c# 2, circa 2006. They're used to better enforce member visibility (an area where Delphi is lacking, since we can't have real private fields in Delphi).

Comment: @Cosmin: What do you mean, we can't have real private fields in Delphi?

Comment: I know. :) The question was about Delphi, and given the example in the original question I can't see why it would be needed; that's why I said so in my answer. If the only goal was to hide the ability to write from outside the class (eg., protect it), my solution works; inside the class, you write to FMyProp directly instead of MyProp.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: isn't `strict private` real private?

Comment: it's not only about making things work, it's about enforcing OOP concepts and documenting them through language constructs alone. I brought up C# because lots of Delphi users use both languages and the idea was probably borrowed. And about your idea, I'd simply skip the declaration of the setter to get a true read only property. The OP originally declared the property as publi, I don't think he wants published.